# Centos 5.9 glibc > 2.10

Tags: centos, glibc

so I have a little problem. I have a piece of software that requires glibc (libstdc++.i686 is that needs glibc) (32 bit version) that is >= 2.10.90-7. The problem is, CentOS 5.9 only has glibc 2.5 or something like that... I have tried installing everything from RPM's etc, I just keep getting a BUNCH of dependencies errors...

Comment: If it is on the EPEL repo, use EPEL; if it isn't, compile it into RPMs from source using [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm). Don't pick random RPMs from nowhere.

Comment: Use CentOS 6, then.

Answer (score 1):

The GLibC in EL should *not* be updated outside of what the distribution creator provides as it could cause issues with existing software; that software is not runnable on CentOS 5 without recompilation.